# How to store a Comparable element in a variable?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, quicksort, comparable

I wrote a program where i have to write out the code for a quicksort. I'm using a Comparable [] array. In order to swap two elements of the array, I have to store one element in a variable. Usually, with a string array, I can store the element in a string variable, but I am not allowed to store the value in a string variable with a  Comparable Array. How can I store one element from this Comparable array outside this array so i can swap the two elements? This is what my program looks like, The part which I am stuck at does not have the code there.

```
import java.io.*;

public class QuickSort{
public static void main (String args[]) {       
    Comparable[] q = Read();
    int l = 0; 
    int x = q.length-1;
    QSortr(q, l, x);
    PrintFxn(q);
}

public static Comparable[] Read() {
String hold[] = new String[1000];
int numin=0;
try{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s; 
        s=br.readLine();
        while (s!=null&& !s.equals("")) {
            hold[numin]= s;
            numin++;
            s=br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Ack!:" + e); }
    Comparable q[] = new String[numin];
    for(int a=0; a<numin; a++) {
        q[a] = hold[a];
    }
    return q; }

public static int QSort( Comparable q[], int l, int x) {
    int r = l +1;
    int m= l;
    int k = l;

while(r<q.length-1){
    if( q[r].compareTo(q[k])<=0){
        m++; r++;  }
    else{ 
        while(q[r].compareTo(q[k])>0&&r<q.length-1){
            r++; }
        m++; 
         //This is where i'm stuck...
        q[r] = q[m];
        q[m] = a[0]; }
    }
    return m;}
public static Comparable [] QSortr(Comparable q [], int l, int x) {
    while(l<x) {
        int a = QSort(q, l, x);
        QSortr(q, l, a-1);
        QSortr(q, a+1, x); }
    return q; }

public static void PrintFxn(Comparable[] q) {
    for(int a=0; a<q.length; a++) {
    System.out.println(q[a]); }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but can't use just, er, use a Comparable?

Comment: That's exactly what i was wondering, is that possible/allowed/logical?

Answer (score 0):

There are many wrong things in this implementation of quick sort "in place", one of which is the condition: `while(r<q.length-1)` - you should stop looping when `r > x`. Another issue is that you don't use `x` (right boundary) at all in QSort. 
Check out the following implementation of [*quickSort*](http://alfasin.com/playing-with-ruby/) - even though it's in Ruby - it's easy to follow: the main idea is to run with two pointers - one from right to left and the other left-to right, stop when they cross each other but while running check to see if there are elements smaller than *pivot* to the right of pivot, and bigger of pivot to the left of pivot - and switch between them.

Comment: Thanks for you help with the first part. But, My teacher wanted us to use this partitioning method because it requires less code. The right bound is there essentially, only as an endpoint.  We did learn both types, but he believed this was better.

Comment: The "in-place" version is not "less code" - it uses less memory space because all the actions are preformed on the array itself without copying it.